# Connect to Oracle database from host running on Virtual Machine

Tags: c#, oracle, virtual-machine, host

I have a VM which is running linux and Oracle Database, I have connected it to SQL developer plus from the host, but I want to connect it to an application running on my host? Is this possible? If so how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [ODP.NET](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html&ei=2OUGU9yBH4WVrAeGqoHoBQ&usg=AFQjCNGXK7jkIhboQolQDlvFN06XmrGw7w&sig2=htJFHE8DmBTv5y_F1sas8g&bvm=bv.61725948,d.bmk), which is the data provider for Oraclet for .Net.
Set up the connection string and use as `ADO.NET`.

Comment: will it support my db that is on vm?